# testdriven.io course Scalable Flask Applications on AWS - Gitlab Docker build issue

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, testdriven.io

I am following along with this [course](https://testdriven.io/courses/scalable-flask-aws/) by testdriven.io and I can't get my pipeline to finish without error. Basically the goal here is to push the image to the gitlab registry.

The `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like

```
stages:
  - docker

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"

cache:
  key: ${CI_JOB_NAME}
  paths:
    - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/services/talk_booking/.venv/

build-python-ci-image:
  image: docker:19.03.0
  services:
    - docker:19.03.0-dind
  stage: docker
  before_script:
    - cd ci_cd/python/
  script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/<my_usrnm>/talk-booking:cicd-python3.9-slim .
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/<my_usrnm>/talk-booking:cicd-python3.9-slim
```

The `ci_ci/python/Dockerfile` looks like

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
RUN mkdir -p /home/gitlab && addgroup gitlab && useradd -d /home/gitlab -g gitlab gitlab && chown gitlab:gitlab /home/gitlab
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
USER gitlab
WORKDIR /home/gitlab
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
ENV PATH=/home/gitlab/.local/bin:$PATH
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true
```

But I am getting this error at the `docker build` stage where it looks to execute `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl`. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
Step 3/8 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
 ---> Running in 8336330cabd7
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [151 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [52.1 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131 NO_PUBKEY F8D2585B8783D481
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 54404762BBB6E853 NO_PUBKEY BDE6D2B9216EC7A8
Reading package lists...
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131 NO_PUBKEY F8D2585B8783D481
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 54404762BBB6E853 NO_PUBKEY BDE6D2B9216EC7A8
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease' is not signed.
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl' returned a non-zero code: 100
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 100
```

Comment: Double check your docker volume has enough storage space or try clearing up some space by running `docker system prune`. Also try using a more recent docker version -- version 19 is quite old. Make sure your host system is up to date as well.

Comment: yes it was the version, I changed it to latest and it works. Using latest probably isn't a good way to do it but they need to update the course with a different docker version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the docker version to 24.0.05 and it works now.

```
stages:
  - docker

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"

cache:
  key: ${CI_JOB_NAME}
  paths:
    - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/services/talk_booking/.venv/

build-python-ci-image:
  image: docker:24.0.5
  services:
    - docker:24.0.5-dind
  stage: docker
  before_script:
    - cd ci_cd/python/
  script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/<my_usrnm>/talk-booking:cicd-python3.9-slim .
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/<my_usrnm>/talk-booking:cicd-python3.9-slim
```